# Applying two equations to one array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new to Python and Numpy, and I've spent a lot of time (days) searching for answers to my question, but I'm getting stumped. I have an array of magnitudes for earthquakes, and I need to convert them to a different form of magnitude (Mb to Mo). For magnitudes less than 4.3, I need to apply one conversion, and for magnitudes greater than or equal, I need to apply a second conversion. I need the output to be in the same order as the input, and that's where I'm hitting a wall. I can get the conversions to output into two separate arrays, but I can't figure out how to write a program that chooses one equation based on the magnitude, applies it and moves on to the next magnitude in the array. Even though the following example is obviously incorrect on many levels, I think it shows what I'm trying to achieve:

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt('OK_mag3.csv')

mag = numpy.asarray(data)

for x in mag:

    if x < 4.3:
        mw = 1.03 + 0.67 * x     
    else:
        mw = 0.1 + 0.88 * x
```

Also, an example of getting half of this correct is:

```
mw = mag[mag<4.3]*0.67+1.03
```

but then I don't know how to incorporate the second equation.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mw = numpy.where(mag < 4.3, 1.03 + 0.67 * mag, 0.1 + 0.88 * mag)
```

See docs on [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). The first parameter will transform `data` into a boolean list, the second two params will calculate the whole vector with one function or another; then `where` selects which of the two results is better based on the boolean.

EDIT: Based on the issues raised in comments, the following does not double the work, and will avoid cases when one of the computations would be invalid - but does still take up a bit of memory for the selector array.

```
mw = numpy.zeros(len(mag))
select = mag < 4.3
mw[select] = 1.03 + 0.67 * mag[select]
select = ~select
mw[select] = 0.1 + 0.88 * mag[select]
```

Comment: Much better than my answer, with one caveat: if `mag` is very large, or the actual computation is more complicated than the OPs, then the intermediate arrays could take up a lot of memory.  I doubt it would come up in practice, but worth noting.

Comment: @sapi: If the computations is complex, yes - because double the work. Arrays being large does not make much difference: I use three extra arrays, but you do too (At least if you weren't using extra `numpy.where`s: `mw < 4.3`, `mw < 4.3` again, `mw[mw < 4.3]`). One of them could be avoided by memoising `mw < 4.3`. Still, in this day and age, 25% more memory is not really that much of an issue.

Comment: What `np.where` does is compute both equations for the full array, then choose one or the other for the output based on the first boolean condition. That makes using `np.where` not a good option e.g. when checking for 0 to avoid division by zero errors...

Comment: @Amadan - Yep, agreed.  Just figured it was worth noting.

Comment: Instead of `select = select == False`, you can simply use `~select`, e.g. `mw[~select] = 0.1 + 0.88 * mag[~select]`.

Comment: The first solution you listed worked brilliantly! I had a feeling it shouldn't be too difficult, but nothing I found seemed applicable to my problem. Thank you so much for your help. (I'll play around with your suggestion in the edit as well, just so I can get more practice.)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `np.where`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr = np.eye(3)

In [3]: arr
Out[3]:
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])

In [4]: arr[np.where(arr==0)] += 2

In [5]: arr
Out[5]:
array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  1.]])
```

In your case, for each condition, you could do something like:

```
mw[np.where(mw < 4.3)] = mw[np.where(mw < 4.3)]*0.67 + 1.03
```

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but wanted to clarify.  I think the implication of your answer is that you'd use a ``where`` clause two times, successively.  For the specific equations listed, this solution works (if you run the *.67 + 1.03 first).  But, more generally, you could run into trouble, right?  For instance, if the equation were *.67 + 5, for a value that was initially 4.2, you could end up running the second equation.  In contrast, Amadan's answer seems to handle this edge case.  That's why I'd go with his/her answer instead.

Comment: All uses of `where` in this answer are unnecessary.

Comment: @BehramMistree - Well, definitely.  I assumed you'd precalculate the indices and work from there.  Amadan's answer is much better in that respect, though.

Comment: I have nothing to do with the downvoting, but it is more clear, as well asfaster, to use the boolean array for indexing without the call to `np.where` to convert them to indices, i.e.: `mw[mw < 4.3] = mw[mw < 4.3]*0.67 + 1.03`. Of course, you would probably want to store the boolean array before, e.g.`mask = mw < 4.3; mw[mask] = mw[mask]*0.67 + 1.03` to avoid duplicated operations.

Comment: As a testament to just how much of a beginner I am... I'd been wondering how to use np.<whatever> instead of numpy.<whatever>. So even though the other answer was easier for my problem, I still found this feedback really helpful! :-)